# How to make sure user doesn't enter letters

Tags: java, input, user-input

In my program the user has to choose what they want to do and then hit the number next to the choice and then hit enter.

Right now I have it so that any number that isn't a choice will give an error but now I want to make sure it says error if the user types in a letter for example "fadhahafvfgfh"

here is my code...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AccountMain {


    public static void selectAccount(){


        System.out.println("Which account would you like to access?");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1 = Business Account ");
        System.out.println("2 = Savings Account");
        System.out.println("3 = Checkings Account");
        System.out.println("4 = Return to Main Menu");

        menuAccount();


    }

    public static void menuAccount(){

        BankMain main = new BankMain();
        BankMainSub sub = new BankMainSub();
        BankMainPart3 main5 = new BankMainPart3();

        Scanner account = new Scanner(System.in);

        int actNum = account.nextInt();

        if (actNum == 1){

            System.out.println("*Business Account*");
            sub.businessAccount();
        }

        else if (actNum == 2){

            System.out.println("*Savings Account*");
            main.drawMainMenu();
        }

        else if (actNum == 3){

            System.out.println("*Checkings Account*");
            main5.checkingsAccount();
        }

        else if (actNum == 4){
            BankMain.menu();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Scanner#hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28int%29) for this.

```
if(account.hasNextInt())
  account.nextInt();
```

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the specified radix using the nextInt() method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

If user does not enter valid then you can say bye bye see you next time like below.

```
    int actNum = 0;
    if(account.hasNextInt()) {
        //Get the account number 
        actNum = account.nextInt();
    }
    else
    {
        return;//Terminate program
    }
```

Else you can show error message and ask user to retry for valid account number.

```
    int actNum = 0;
    while (!account.hasNextInt()) {
        // Out put error
        System.out.println("Invalid Account number. Please enter only digits.");
        account.next();//Go to next
    }
    actNum = account.nextInt();
```

Comment: How exactly would I use this in my code? Sorry I'm still new to java

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner account = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = 0;
while (true and count < 3) {
    if (!account.hasNextInt()) {
        int actNum = account.nextInt();
        break;
    } else {
         System.out.println("Enter an integer");
         count++;
         account.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will loop forever for one error condition :). You will also need to to read account.next() inside loop

Comment: There's a better one now.. :)

Comment: Err Still there is a problem, in else you need to do a account.next() so that it will go to next() element.

Comment: Oh yes.. nextInt() doesn't move pointer to next character... Thanks for quoting.. Will edit it..  My Brain in `rusted`..  :-\

Answer (score 1):

i think the accepted answer is correct, but we should make use of java features like exception handling in our code

// so our code should look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int choice=0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringReverse objReverse = new StringReverse();

    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("1.Reverse String");
    System.out.println("2.Exit");

    do {
            System.out.println("Enter your choice");
            try {
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
                switch(choice) {

                     case 1 :
                            System.out.println("Enter the string to reverse");
                            String inputString = new String();
                            inputString = scanner.next();
                            String reversedString = objReverse.reverse(inputString );
                            System.out.println("Reversed String is " + reversedString);
                            break;

                     case 2 :
                            System.out.println("Exiting...");
                            return;

                     default :
                            System.out.println("Default choice");
                            break;
               }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter valid integer input");
                    scanner.next();
            }
   } while(choice != 2);
}
```

Comment: @Prashant my pleasure bro

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner has a [hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) function that returns true if the next token is a Integer. So before calling `nextInt()` validate if `hasNextInt()` is true. If it fails, show a message to the user asking him to enter an integer. Note, The Integer doesn't necessarily needs to fall in your required range, so make sure you also have a final `else` to inform the user the number he entered was invalid.

Tip: Use Switch Case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scanner.hasNextInt()` or `Integer.parseInt()`.

```
Scanner account = new Scanner(System.in);
String actNum = account.next();
try {
    Integer.parseInt(actNum);
} catch(ParseException ex) {
    sysout("please enter only numeric values")
}
```

Comment: actNum is already an `int`, your parse code will never be called as an exception will be raised at `nextInt` first